# Bukkit - Update a sign every second

Tags: scheduler, bukkit

I am trying to make a sign update every second, but I just don't know what to do.
I already have a finished code with a scheduler, but I just don't know where I should put it.

It would be very very nice if someone could help me or even give me an example code...

Here is my code:

```java
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    DateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date d = new Date();


    public void onEnable() {
            System.out.println("[BookshelfDrop] BookshelfDrop v" + this.getDescription().getVersion() + " enabled");
            getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);


    }

    public void onDisable() {
            System.out.println("[BookshelfDrop] BookshelfDrop disabled");
    }




    @EventHandler
    public void onChange(SignChangeEvent event) {

    if (event.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("[clock]")) {
        Sign s = (Sign) event.getBlock().getState();
        s.setLine(0, "[clock]");
        Bukkit.getServer()
          .getScheduler()
          .scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(
             Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("BookshelfDrop"),
             new Runnable() {

             public void run() {
                 s.setLine(1, "§a" + dFormat.format(d));
                 s.update();
             }
         }, 0, 20L);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us all of your code? It would really help us answer your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all of my code, except for the onEnable and onDisable Method...The only thing I also have is my TimeFormat: ´DateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 Date d = new Date();´

Comment: it would help if you showed **everything**, including the `onEnable()` and `onDisable()` methods

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sxeaVLnA - My code

Comment: I know, it's called "BookshelfDrop" but it's because I didn't change the names yet, so....

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't update. I want it to update constantly, I just don't know how. The scheduler code would work, I just don't know where...

Comment: Try using `this` in place of the argument `Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("BookshelfDrop")`.

Comment: I don't think you nderstand my problem. I need to always update the sign. Maybe if I put it in PlayerMoveEvent but that would not be the perfect solution....

Answer (score -1):

You can create an ArrayList to put all your signs

```
public ArrayList<Sign> yourSigns = new ArrayList<Sign>();
```

Then add this to your onSignChange

```
public void onChange(SignChangeEvent event) {
 if (event.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("[clock]")) {
 Sign s = (Sign) event.getBlock().getState();
 yourSigns.add(s);
}
```

On your onEnable() method, you can then put your clock, making a loop through each sign on your signs list.